# detecting when a usb drive is connected script not working as intended

Tags: linux, bash, usb, dwm, tiling-wm

im using DWM (Tiling Window Manager) with `dwmblocks` for the statusbar on my laptop. i have 3 usb ports on this laptop. im using this script to detect and show a block(icon) on the statusbar when i connect a usb drive.

```
if [[ "$(dmesg -S | tail | grep "usb-storage")" =~ "USB Mass Storage device detected" ]]; then
           icon=" ️ "
           else
           icon=""
   fi
   
   printf "%s%s\\n" "$icon"
```

but this script is not good enough. when i connect 1 usb it gives this

```
[  151.134547] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  151.138129] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[  152.157810] scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MBIL SSM Moser Baer Disk  8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  152.158051] sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[  152.158711] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] 31027200 512-byte logical blocks: (15.9 GB/14.8 GiB)
[  152.159381] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[  152.159387] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[  152.160066] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  152.924036]  sdb: sdb1 sdb2 sdb3
[  152.926370] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

when i connect another usb at the same time it gives this

```
[  364.948449] scsi host3: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[  366.206529] scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     SRT      USB              1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[  366.206834] sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  366.207126] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] 15818752 512-byte logical blocks: (8.10 GB/7.54 GiB)
[  366.207629] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[  366.207631] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
[  366.208117] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[  366.208119] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[  366.237610]  sdc: sdc1
[  366.239332] sd 3:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

which doesn't have usb-storage to grep so the icon disappears even though i have 2 usb connected.

when i connect a usb portable 2.5" hdd it gives this ( i extended tail range to -n 15 )

```
[  659.426376] usb 1-3: Product: USB 3.0 Device
[  659.426377] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: USB 3.0 Device
[  659.426379] usb 1-3: SerialNumber: 00000000B032
[  659.433060] scsi host4: uas
[  659.433839] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WDC WD10 SPZX-00Z10T0     0117 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[  659.435213] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[  659.435840] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[  659.435842] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] 4096-byte physical blocks
[  659.436038] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[  659.436041] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 53 00 10 08
[  659.436349] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Disabling FUA
[  659.436351] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[  659.436476] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Optimal transfer size 33553920 bytes not a multiple of physical block size (4096 bytes)
[  659.578561]  sdd: sdd1
[  659.580012] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI disk
```

usb hdd doesn't even have a usb-storage to grep.

also when 1 of the flash drive was connected and i rebooted the icon didn't show because the dmesg tail was about my wifi being connected and networkmanager.

any idea's for improving this script, as this is not reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure

> by using udiskctl dump

```
 #!/bin/bash
  
   if [[ "$(udisksctl dump|awk -F':\n' -vRS= '/[ \t]*HintAuto:[ \t]*true/&&/\.Filesystem:/{print "found"}')" != "" ]]; then
           icon="  "
   else
           icon=""
   fi
  
   printf "%s%s\\n" "$icon"
```

you can get away with

```
udisksctl dump|grep 'HintAuto:\s*true'
```

if you don't have a cd/dvd drive or card reader